# Why is breaks_width offsetting my data when plotting with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, offset

When I'm plotting data like this

> ```
> start_date = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00")
> end_date = as.POSIXct("2020-01-02 00:00")
> ggplot(NULL, aes(x=seq(start_date, end_date, by=60), y=c(1))) +
>   geom_col() +
>   scale_x_datetime(breaks=breaks_width(width = "6 hours"), labels = date_format("%H", tz=Sys.timezone()))
> ```

I'd expect to have breaks at `00:00`, `06:00`, `12:00` and `18:00` (since no offset in the `breaks_width` function is provided it defaults to zero). Somehow the result looks like this

[image]

I can achieve the expected outcome by manually setting the offset to -4 hours like this

> ```
> breaks=breaks_width(width = "6 hours", offset=-4*60*60)
> ```

but I don't understand why this should be necessary. Is it possible that this is a bug?

Comment: Try this: `scale_x_datetime(breaks=seq(from=start_date, by=4*3600, length.out=7), date_labels = "%H %Z")`

Comment: @Dave2e This gives the correct spacing (0, 4, 8, ..., 20, 0) in the format `04 CET`. The sequence does work correctly. I'm still wondering why an extra offset is necessary with `breaks_width`? Has it something to do with the timezones?

Comment: I not quite sure what the cause behind it, maybe a time zone offset but also maybe how ggplot sets a margin for creating the labels for the axis.